# Ссылка в tkinter не работает в самом меню, подскажите что не так

Tags: python, tkinter, webbrowser

```
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser

def callback(event):
    webbrowser.open_new(r"https://www.google.ru")


root = Tk()
root.geometry('230x110')
root.title('тест')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

main_menu = Menu()

Help_menu = Menu(tearoff=0)
Help_menu.add_command(label="тык", command=callback)

main_menu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=Help_menu)

root.config(menu=main_menu)
m2 = Button(root, text="google", padx="72", pady="5", command=callback)
m2.place(x=15, y=60)
m2.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
root.mainloop()
```

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\AlexTrask\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
   return self.func(*args)
TypeError: callback() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'
```

Comment: Что означает "Ссылка в tkinter не работает в самом меню"?

Comment: выходит ошибка,  действий нет

Comment: Текст ошибки добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: `Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AlexTrask\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: callback() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'`

Comment: Просто удалите параметр event у функции callback.

Comment: да, Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AlexTrask\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: callback() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: Приведенный в вопросе код не вызывает такую ошибку. Такая ошибка может быть только если вы убрали параметр event и через bind добавили привязку callback к какому-то событию.

Comment: но как быть с ошибкой, если мне нужно что бы ссылка работала как с кнопки так и с меню

Comment: Добавьте весь код. В коде в вопросе нет никакой кнопки.

Comment: дело в том что когда я добавляю кнопку то с меню ссылка перестает работать и работает только через кнопку но всегда одна ошибка
`Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AlexTrask\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: callback() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'`

Comment: Удалите строку `m2.bind("<Button-1>", callback)` (callback у вас уже привязан к кнопке через параметр command кнопки) и удалите параметр event у функции callback.

Comment: понял, спасибо так и правда лучше!!!!!